# adding new points with mouse click and adding them to the existing attribute table

Tags: arcpy, point, arcgis-10.4, python-addin

I am quite a beginner with programming in python and I am struggling with my code. I would like to create new points(trees) on my map using mouse click and afterwards add them to the existing attribute table. I managed to locate points with mouse click however they are not added to the table, it is always one row (even I added 10 points) and the columns(ID, tree, Lat and Long) are not there as well (only ID, Shape..). I tried to connect it directly to the existing data set but then when I locate a new tree all other trees are disappearing and attribute table is containing one row as well.

```py
     def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
         #adding points to the map
         mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
         sr = mxd.activeDataFrame.spatialReference
         pntFc = r"\\abc\home\xxx\Documents\moje dokumenty\xyz\arcgis\treepoints" #new polygon
         ofc=r"\\abc\home\xxx\Documents\moje dokumenty\xyz\arcgis\trees" #existing data set 
         fields=["OID@","Tree","Lat", "Long"]
         Lat="SHAPE@X"
         Long="SHAPE@Y"
         pt = arcpy.Point()
         pt.X = float(x)
         pt.Y = float(y)
         ptGeoms = [arcpy.Geometry ("POINT", pt, sr)]
         if not arcpy.Exists (pntFc):
              arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeoms, pntFc)
         else:
             with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (pntFc, fields) as iCurs: #create insert cursor
             #insert row
                for pt in ptGeoms:
                    row=iCurs.insertRow()
               arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        print "Complete"
```

Comment: `row=iCurs.insertRow()` is not pushing anything into your cursor because it has no parameter values being supplied to it.  Also, your indentation seems to be a little astray.  Have you tried having your Python window open when you click the button so that you can see any error messages?

Comment: Yes, I have python window open and it does not show any errors

Comment: I think you must have an error in your program.arcpy.da.InsertCursor you should have a good look

Comment: No error at all...I have printed also the messages after all stages and they were printed so I guess all steps are made.